# insmod: error when inserting DPDK igb_uio.ko module

Tags: dpdk

I use centos 7.3. When I run insmod igb_uio.ko, I get this error in /var/logs/message:

- igb_uio: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
- WARNING: module'igb_uio' built without retpoline-enable compiler, may affect Spectre v2 mitigation
- igb_uio: module verification failed: signature and/or
  required key missing - tainting kernel.
- igb_uio: disagrees about
  version of symol __uio_register_device
- igb_uio: Unknown symbol
  __uio_register_device (err -22) ...

This happens after I did some patches to OS and kernel. After patch, the kernel version is: 3.10.0.957.21.3.e17.x86_64

Before patch, it works well. The patch is for some TCP critical vulnerability. I prefer to run the patch.

I use DPDK 17.08.1, I also tried 18.11.2. Both get same error.

I try to rebuild from source, after patch. The rebuild get errors: (before patch, build is successfully.):

- make: *** /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/build: No such file
  or directory.  Stop.
- make[6]: *** [igb_uio.ko] Error 2
- make[5]: ***
  [igb_uio] Error 2
- make[4]: *** [linux] Error 2
- make[3]: ***
  [kernel] > Error 2
- make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
- make[1]: ***
  [pre_install] Error 2
- make:
  *** [install] Error 2

Comment: When I use CentOS 7.6, also has same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your igb_uio module against the right kernel headers. If you patched/updated the kernel then you should do the same for the headers. If your headers are patched but you still get the errors then try compiling it like this:

```
RTE_KERNELDIR=/path/to/headers make -j
```

Answer (score 2):

To insert `igb_uio` module, you have to insert the `uio` module first. Then, inserting `igb_uio` will work correctly.

In any case, i would suggest using VFIO rather than `igb_uio` unless you specifically require `igb_uio`.

Also, if you're building custom kernels, you should add the relevant header/module paths, to ensure that building modules against this custom kernel works. (meaning, when the compiler does `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/`, the path must exist)

Comment: when i use igb_uio, I did add: modprobe uio, insmod .../igb_uio.ko. For VFIO, I did a try, the file vfio-pci.ko is inside /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kenel/drivers/vfio/pci folder. I called modprobe vfio-pci. From status, I can see: 0000:01:00.2 'Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ 1572' if=ens11f2 drv=i40e unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci. Then I bind vfio-pci: ./bind.py --bind=vfio-pci 0000:01:00.2. It failed to bind. From /var/log/message, I get this error: Sep 19 17:38:48 r2 kernel: vfio-pci: probe of 0000:01:00.2 failed with error -22

Comment: If you get a -22 error when inserting VFIO module, you don't have virtualization enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As I know,

This error derives from mismatch or deficiency of kernel-devel packets with the current kernel.

If the current kernel version is not consistent with kernel-devel,
`/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/` could not generated properly.
In my case, the kernel that I working on is 4.13.12-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64, but kernel-devel packets belong to 3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64 .

My solution is installing kernel-devel that consistent with the current kernel by

```
yum update
yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
```

If packets could not found, manual installation using rpm may be required. In my case, I wget kernel-ml-devel-4.14.13-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64.rpm packet and
remove old kernel-devel by

```
yum remove kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64
yum remove kernel-devel-3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64
```

and I install correct devel packets by

```
sudo rpm -i kernel-ml-devel-4.13.12-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64.rpm
```

Finally, dpdk compiles with no error in my case.